# Increase font size of 1 cell of a table

Tags: html, css, fonts

If I have a td and need to increase the font of that specific cell by X points of what it has after all styles have been applied how would I do that? I don't need to do it in css. I mean I am fine if I just add something in the td tag itself.
I am not pasting code as it is part of an existing page (complicated) and I am interested in only modifying 1 cell of the table

**Update**
My question is how to increase the size of font of the specific cell without using an absolute font

Comment: Give it an ID, grab with JS and increase the font size?

Comment: @Blunderfest:It is not about grabbing it. But how to increase the current size a bit more.I.e. not put an absolute size.

Answer (score 2):

Most simple is to add a `class` or `id` to your cell.

You could use a class: `<td class='thisOne'>` or id `<td id='thisOne'>` and style it with `.thisOne { font-size: 1.2em; }` or `#thisOne{ font-size: 1.2em; }`.

If you aren't able to change the HTML, you can use the [structural pseudo-classes](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Selectors#Structural_pseudo-classes).

Some examples:

```
tr:nth-child(5) td:nth-child(2) { font-size: 1.2em; } // fifth row, second cell
tr:first-child td:last-child { font-size: 1.2em; } // first row, last cell
```

Comment: Is this in relation to the current size?

Comment: Yes, by default the font size is `1em` (from it's parent). `1.2em` is the same as `120%`

Answer (score 1):

I Would suggest using css. Add a class to the td and css like so;

```
    td.myclass {
font-size: 1.5em;
}
```

Alternativeley you can add as an inline style like below;

```
<td style="font-size:1.5em;">Text here</td>
```

Comment: yes, if 1.5 is not correct check here; http://pxtoem.com/ You can select the correct em based on your font size in px. Please note px also works inline

Comment: But how do I know the exact px size if the page is created by various css?

Comment: They should be set in body, the default is normally set at 16px. You do not have to use em, if it makes things more diffuclt you can just put an inlint style for font and use px instead of em.

Comment: You can inspect using firebug and you should find out what size is being used. I would be happy to take a look if you send over a link.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible with CSS alone. Using `font-size: calc(100% + 5px)` (assuming X equals 5; see [MDN on `calc`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc)) comes closest, but here `100%` refers to the parent element’s font size, not the font size of the element itself as determined by all CSS rules involved.

It can be done with the help of JavaScript, but then you need to use the [`getComputedStyle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.getComputedStyle) method, which is not supported by all browsers. If you can ignore IE 8 and older or handle them in another way, you can use code like the following (assuming, for simplicity, that you do not otherwise use JavaScript):

```
<table>
<tr><td>foo
<td id=xyz>foo
</table>
<script>
window.onload = function() {
  var cell = document.getElementById('xyz');
  var size = getComputedStyle(cell, null).getPropertyValue('font-size');
  cell.style.fontSize = (parseInt(size) + 5) + 'px';
}
</script>
```

This just finds out the computed font size value, which is in the `px` units, gets the numeric value, adds the desired increment, appends `px`, and sets the font size for the cell.

Comment: What the @Jay replied seems to be working.May be I am not understanding something?

Comment: Other answers increase the font size by some relative amount, relative to some size. That might well be better, but what you actually asked is how to increase by a fixed amount in pixels, and this is what my answer deals with. (I have added a reference to `calc` documentation, which may be relevant in *similar* problems, but not in this one.)

Comment: I may not have been accurate due to my not knowing enough on the topic. But your answer is interesting +1

Answer (score 0):

you can add the style to the cell just as below:

```
<td style="font-size:150%">cell Information here..</td>
```

you can change 150 to whichever value you want.